# Derby Network Server - Accept connections from multiple hosts - derby.drda.host

Tags: java, derby

Derby [documentation](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/adminguide/radmindrdahost.html) says

> derby.drda.host=hostname
>
> The property listens to a host for network connections i.e. accepts
>   connections from them. If 0.0.0.0 is specified, connections from any
>   host is accepted.

Now, I have three remote computers, `hostA`, `hostB`, `hostC`.

- My derby server is running on `hostA`.
- I want derby server to listen for connections from `hostA`, `hostB`, `hostC`

So, I wrote

```
props.setProperty("derby.drda.host", "hostA hostB hostC");
```

However, this does not work. **Is there some other way ?**

**Edit:**

When I set the property as

```
props.setProperty("derby.drda.host" , "hostA");
```

then `hostB` and `hostC` are **not** able to connect to server. They get below exception

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException
>   : Error connecting to server hostA on port 8,888 with message
>   Connection refused: connect.

However, when I set property as

```
props.setProperty("derby.drda.host" , "0.0.0.0");
```

then all hosts (`hostA`, `hostB`, `hostC`) are able to connect to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've misunderstood what this property is used for. This is so that you can tell Derby on which IP of the server to accept connections, if you have multiple network interfaces. (A lot of servers have more than one network card, or are connected to several networks at the same time and thus have several IP-s).

The default setting of `0.0.0.0` means that it should accept any connection being requested on any of the server's IP-s. If you set this value to something other than `0.0.0.0`, it will listen just for connections targeting just that IP.

This does not limit the client connections based on ***their*** IP.

I believe you need to have the following set:

```
System.setProperty("derby.drda.startNetworkServer", "true");
```

In order to start Derby as a network server (and not just run it in the JVM, as I believe the default behaviour was).

Comment: You mean a server may have more than one IP (interface) and this property is to tell derby which interface (by specifying IP) to listen for connections. Specifying `0.0.0.0` means derby should listen to any IP (interface) on that server. RIght ?

Comment: But I have observed one thing. When I start server with `props.setProperty("derby.drda.host","hostA")` then remote clients fail to connect, when i specify props.setProperty("derby.drda.host"   , "0.0.0.0")` then remote clients are able to connect.. Why so ?

Comment: To your first comment -- yes; to the second one, what are the actual IP-s?

Comment: For actual IPs, all hosts are local to LAN, so they are `192.168.10 / 11 / 12` for `hostA / hostB / hostC`

Comment: Oh, then what should I provide ?

Comment: Oh.. Sorry.. My bad.. I mistyped the comment. They are `192.168.1.10`, `192.168.1.11`, `192.168.1.12`

Comment: Does this help: `props.setProperty("derby.drda.host" , "192.168.1.0");`? (I don't think it should, because I believe it needs to be the IP of the server, but you can give it a try).

Comment: When i set th property `derby.drda.host` as `192.168.1.11` means (hostB), for a server running on hostA,  and then i run program on `hostB` to connect to server (`hostA`), it still fails to connect

Comment: Ok, I tried with subnet `192.168.1.0`, it still fails to connect

Comment: You are setting this on the server's side, not the client's, right?

Comment: Yes server side. Client side is not setting this property. it is just connecting to URL `jdbc:derby://hostA:8888/myDB`